# A kernel crash produced by Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I saw a nice plot on [Kaurov](http://kaurov.com/wordpress/?p=882)

```
Plot3D[
Im[Sec[(x + I y)^4]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
Mesh -> None,  
ClippingStyle -> None,  
PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.8], Specularity[White, 20]],  
PlotPoints -> 50]
```

and I tried to reproduce it varying some parameters, by means of

```
plot[index_] := Plot3D[
Im[Sec[(x + I y)^index]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
Mesh -> None, 
ClippingStyle -> None, 
PlotStyle -> 
Directive[Orange, Opacity[.8], Specularity[White, 20]], 
PlotPoints -> 50];
```

but `plot[0]` makes the kernel crumble  each time of a lot of runs. 
  Do you think it' s a bug or comes from some instability in my machine ?

(Mathematica 8.0.1.0, Ms Xp ver. 5.1.2600)

Comment: Can you try removing the `PlotStyle` setting?

Comment: I did. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in *Mathematica* 8 and 9, but appears to be fixed by 10.3.  As a workaround, I suggest wrapping the function with `Evaluate` so that it symbolically preprocesses the expression before making a plot:

```
plot[index_] := 
  Plot3D[Evaluate[Im[Sec[(x + I y)^index]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Mesh -> None, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.8], Specularity[White, 20]], 
  PlotPoints -> 50];
```